# Index or partition on SCD 2 table commonly rolled up from daily to monthly snapshots

Tags: sql, query-optimization, teradata, database-administration

I have a very large table which gets loaded daily.  The business user is mostly only interested in monthly snapshots (latest record by key field each month).

For example:

```
Loan_Number   Balance    Load_Date
1             $1         4/25/2016
1             $.75       2/15/2015
1             $1.50      4/13/2016
2             $2         1/1/2016
2             $2.75      4/30/2016
2             $2.50      5/05/2016
2             $2         4/15/2016
3             $3         5/05/2016
3             $3.50      5/15/2016
```

The April snapshot would be:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Loan_Table
 WHERE Load_Date <= DATE '4/30/2016'
QUALIFY 
       row_number() OVER(
           PARTITION BY Loan_Number 
               ORDER BY Load_Date DESC) 
           = 1
```

Are there any index or partition structures that could be added to this table to improve the performance?  We're running TD 14 if that helps.

Comment: What's the current PI? Based on your WHERE-condition *April* might also include rows from earlier months?

Comment: @dnoeth Current PI is Loan_Number.  Yes, in this scenario if the account balance hasn't changed since February that would happen.  Load_Date is actually a system generated insert time stamp.  A new record for a loan is only loaded when there's been a balance change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PI on `Load_Number` is probably the best you can get, partitioning won't help. Explain hopefully shows 'STAT FUNCTION ... built locally`.

But depending on row count & record size a good old NUSI plus MAX might help:

```
CREATE INDEX (Loan_Number, Load_Date) ORDER BY HASH(Loan_Number) ON Loan_Table;

SELECT * 
  FROM Loan_Table AS t1
 WHERE Load_Date = 
  ( SELECT MAX(Load_Date ) 
    FROM Loan_Table AS t2
    WHERE t1.Loan_Number = t2.Loan_Number 
      AND Load_Date  <= DATE '2016-04-30'
  )
```

Comment: Will Teradata avoid sorting the data again if the column is already sorted because of NUSI?

Comment: @xenodevil: In which case? This NUSI is sorted by Hash value? +Check Explain, probably not.